# Compiling Unicorn Linux C API on Raspberry PI 4

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors, g++, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to compile this github repository on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 18.04. The code is written on c++.

https://github.com/unicorn-bi/Unicorn-Suite-Hybrid-Black/tree/master/Unicorn%20Raspberry%20Pi%20Zero%20W%20C%20API/UnicornCAPIAcquisitionExample

When I run the following line as in the example:

```
g++ main.cpp -I ../Lib -L ../Lib -lunicorn -o UnicornAcquisitionExample
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../Lib/libunicorn.so when searching for -lunicorn
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunicorn
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems the shared library file is not compatible. This is weird since it should run also on the Raspberry Pi 4. I have tried to replicate the shared library file and I have tried to compile it also without it. I get always the following error:

```
/tmp/ccrr59RO.o: In function 'main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to 'UNICORN_GetAvailableDevices'
main.cpp:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to 'UNICORN_GetAvailableDevices'
main.cpp:(.text+0x300): undefined reference to 'UNICORN_OpenDevice'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3e8): undefined reference to 'UNICORN_GetNumberOfAcquiredChannels'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3f4): undefined reference to 'UNICORN_GetConfiguration'
main.cpp:(.text+0x53c): undefined reference to 'UNICORN_StartAcquisition'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5e0): undefined reference to 'UNICORN_GetData'
main.cpp:(.text+0x654): undefined reference to 'UNICORN_StopAcquisition'
main.cpp:(.text+0x6fc): undefined reference to 'UNICORN_CloseDevice'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure if I should try to replicate the shared library file or doing without it but in either case I get always the following error. How can I compile the example in the github on the Raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: Yes, the shared library is incompatible.

Comment: Is there a way I can generate the shared library and make it work on the raspberry pi4? Or some other way to make it compile on the raspberry pi4?

Comment: Sure, get the source code to the shared library, and compile it from the source code.

Comment: I don't think the source is available. That is the problem. Is there another way?

Comment: No there isn't.